# Exim4: How to add or rewrite Reply-to: header in outgoing messages?

Tags: debian, configuration, email-server, exim, smtp-headers

How can I configure *exim header rewriting* to take care of **forgotten** `Reply-To:` **headers** in emails leaving our company?

We want to have certain `Reply-To:` headers added to all official
emails leaving the company. E.g. `Reply-To: sales@company.example.com`, 
`Reply-To: support@company.example.com`, ...

A single person might get sick, take a day off, go on a vacation or something like this.  The addresses mentioned as example `Reply-To:` addresses above are aliases which distribute the incoming replies from clients to a group of colleagues in order to make sure that somebody will read and act on them in a timely manner.

I've studied [the filter section of the exim documentation](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-4.30/doc/html/filter_3.html#SECT3.21) but I still feel unable to apply this to my particular problem.  A working example would be fine.

Our mail server is debian based and uses the so called *split configuration scheme* if this matters.

Comment: Headers can be added in the ACLs and routers by directive `headers_add` (ch.15 Exim spec). May be you have to check sender_address against some lists and then add the header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    acl_smtp_rcpt    = acl_rcpt
    begin acl
    acl_rcpt:
      warn   domains = !+local_domains
           condition = ${lookup{$sender_address}lsearch{/path/salesmen.list}{yes}}
       remove_header = Reply-to
          add_header = Reply-to: sales@domain.com

      warn   domains = !+local_domains
           condition = ${lookup{$sender_address}lsearch{/path/servicemen.list}{yes}}
       remove_header = Reply-to
          add_header = Reply-to: support@domain.com
. . . . .
```

Lists are plaintext files with one email address per line